# Why am I getting exception Directory Is Not empty?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this line:

```
Directory.Delete(outputfiles, true);
```

If I set it to `true` then it should also delete subdirectories and files.
Now I checked that the directory is empty so it will be deleted next time.
But before the exception in this directory I had another 4 subdirectories and in one of them I had a zip file of about 7 Mb size.

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024751
  Message=The directory is not empty.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)
       at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)
       at Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen.CreateDirectories.CreateDirectoriesAtConstructor() in d:\C-Sharp\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\CreateDirectories.cs:line 35
       at Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen.Form1..ctor() in d:\C-Sharp\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Form1.cs:line 125
       at Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Tried now again and same exception. And i checked twice now im in the directory in the explorer and its empty.

Comment: Now its working now the exception is not throw up. Strange. Not sure why.

Comment: from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx *The directory specified by path is read-only, or recursive is false and path is not an empty directory.* Is it possible the directory is read only?

Comment: from the same source: `In some cases, if you have the specified directory open in File Explorer, the Delete method may not be able to delete it.`

Comment: Also read-only or files being accessed will cause failure. Is this a post-operation cleanup? (maybe you still have a file handle on the zip file that's open?)

Comment: Are you able to do that operation manually?

Answer (score 10):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx):

> If the recursive parameter is true, the user must have write
>   permission for the current directory as well as for all
>   subdirectories.

Could be that the user doesn't have write permission?

Or this one:

> In some cases, if you have the specified directory open in File
>   Explorer, the Delete method may not be able to delete it.

Comment: Im getting the same error when developing locally, it turns out that if you got the folder open in Explorer the exception will be thrown.